# QGIS 3 - Where are Layer Variables?

Tags: qgis-3

I've dug through lots of docs and [this blog](http://nyalldawson.net/2015/12/exploring-variables-in-qgis-pt-3-layer-level-variables/), but I'm confounded.
I go to Layer Properties, but there's no Variables section. What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You opened Raster Layer Properties and "Variable" tab doesn't exist for raster layers. You should open a vector layer properties.

Comment: This is what I was missing, I'm new to qgis and did not see this in the docs anywhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the Layers Panel:

1. select a layer;
2. right mouse button
3. select properties

[image]